# Can't start this react app using npm start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am trying to run someone else's react app. In the description it's written in order to run it i should do the following

To run the webpack dev script run npm start [appname].

[appname] represents an app domain name in the test server. [appname] must be passed so that the app has a data structure. You can choose from any app in the test server.

What does[appname] mean exactly? Could you'll give me an example as to what command I could write in order to get this app started?

Edit: npm start would not work. This was because it was scripted in a way where you need to append something after it. I contacted the creator of this repo and he helped me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm start would not work because it was scripted in a way where you need to append something after it. After reading the package.json I contacted the creator of this repo and he helped me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to run npm start command only, If you face any error then share package.json and error.